# External door slamming

Tags: doors, sealing

I have metallic external door, that has rubber seal around the perimeter. When I try to close the door, I have to bump it, in order to press the seal and allow latch to move out. So the question is: are there any door locks with a latch, that can catch on the door jamb when the door is not yet closed by a few millimeters? And when it has catched, it should continue closing and press the seal by itself, without my help. Looks like I can't find right keywords for Google.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the door and/or latch would be helpful here.

Comment: If you use an automatic door closer of the correct type, it will pull or push your door closed until it latches if it's adjusted correctly. No "bump" required.